Is there a way to print the current line number in XCode?
Does XCode have some sort of macro which outputs the current line number?
For trouble shooting I add a few print() statements, and currently manually insert the line number. Something like this:
print("73: \(value)")

It would be nice if XCode count insert the line number for me.
I’m using Swift.

It's available, try this:
print("\(#line): \(value)")

You're also able to print out #function, #file, etc... take a look at this Literal-Expression
